# How can I switch between multiple WEBView in each test Appium

Tags: mobile, appium, appium-android, testautomationfx

During my tests, I pass the Webview and interact with the related fields with the following code. Everything is fine until here.

```
  ((AndroidDriver) getDriver()).context((String) handles.toArray()[1]);

    Object[] windowHandles = getDriver().getWindowHandles().toArray();
    getDriver().switchTo().window(windowHandles[windowHandles.length - 3].toString());

    System.out.println("Current Context " + ((AndroidDriver) getDriver()).getContext());
```

Then I switch context native and exit and closeApp

when I want to enter the same webview, I’m switching the context again as above. again and do another test operation. it does not enter the webview window I want.

[image]